# CQLSH - Check for null in where clause for MAP Data type

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

CASSANDRA Version : 2.1.10

```
CREATE TABLE customer_raw_data (
  id uuid,
  hash_prefix bigint,
  profile_data map<varchar,varchar>
  PRIMARY KEY (hash_prefix,id));
```

I have an index on profile_data and I have row where profile_data is null.

**How to write a select query to retrieve the rows where profile_data is null ?**

I tried the following

```
select count(*) from customer_raw_data where profile_data=null;

select count(*) from customer_raw_data where profile_data CONTAINS KEY null;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT in cassandra where id != null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456188/select-in-cassandra-where-id-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Reference to : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3783

**There is currently no select support for indexed nulls, and given the design of Cassandra, is considered a difficult/prohibitive problem.**

Answer (score 1):

[image]Basic problem.
where condition column has to be either primary key or secondary index so make your column what-ever is suitable and then try below query.
Try this..

> select count(*) from customer_raw_data where profile_data='';

Comment: I have a secondary index on column profile_data and for your query I get below error 

InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Collection column 'profile_data' (map<text, text>) cannot be restricted by a '=' relation"

Comment: I did not insert any value, just made that field blank. so you can also do the same instead of inserting as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE colName > 5000 ALLOW FILTERING;   //Work fine

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE colName > 5000 limit 10 ALLOW FILTERING;

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/old/CQL-3.0.html

Check the "ALLOW FILTERING" Part.