# What NoSQL database could accommodate the following data structure?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I want to create a database of events. Events by the same user would have the same user id. I could then execute queries to retrieve users who had done events A and B but not C.

I've had a look at Cassandra but I'm unclear about how I should model this data.

The approach I thought of would be:

Every entry in the database gets a unique id (because I think Cassandra requires a unique primary key?), and then I have one column which is my user id, non-unique. Then I am free to give each event other columns, depending on what is relevant to that event. So I might have some entries:

```
1,user1,event_column=registered,fname_column=James,lname_column=Mason
2,user2,event_column=deleted
3,user1,event_column=pageview,page_column=homepage
```

and so on.

Then I'm a bit unclear about how I would select users who had done A and B but not C. Could I do that with one query? Or would I need to bring into java all users who had done A, then all users who had done B and filter for users in common?

Does that approach sound possible and a good way to use Cassandra?

Are there other open source distributed databases which might be appropriate?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With a secondary index on the "event_column" you can ask `...WHERE event_column IN ('A', 'B')`, but you cannot do a `NOT IN` clause like in conventional SQL. (See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498445/how-to-perform-not-in-filter-in-cql3-query-select)).

An example of a database that supports your query is [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) where [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/nin/) and [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/) are similar to `NOT IN (...)` and `IN (...)`, respectively. (MongoDB is a document database where Cassandra is a column database.)
In order to prevent a complete scan of all documents, remember to put a secondary index on the `events` property if only a minority of documents will contain the events that you search for.

Comment: Thanks for this (OP, different account). I suspect we may be talking at cross purposes. To take the MongoDB example, I don't want to identify documents where the event is in(..) or not in (..). I want to identify users, that do have one document associated with them for event A, and who also have another document associated with them for event B. I don't think the in() operator will do this? It would be more like a subselect I think, but I'm not sure what the equivalent would be in MongoDB, or whether I'd just have to handle it in the app - or perhaps with MapReduce? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Just wanted to add, secondary index over cassandra is a very bad idea.
Reason being, metadata for secondary index is not shared among all the nodes, 
and for each query based on secondary index, each node will have to query within itself.

So, if query with primary index takes 2 internal query, query with secondary index will require query * number of cassandra nodes.